# visual studio: multiple projects with same name in one solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I've encountered something strange with visual studio 2015 and 2017.
In visual studio 2012 you can create a solution with the structure that is illustrated in the following picture.

[image: project structure]

and you can add references to both library projects (F1/Common) and (F2/Common) in say Wapp project. nothing special. but in visual studio 2015 and 2017 you will receive this error dialog if you try to do that.

[image: error dialog]

is this a bug in visual studio (2015 - 2017) or there is a configuration for that in visual studio options and settings?

appreciation for your response

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is to rename the project in the Solution.

Add the second project under the name "Common2" and then rename the project in the solution explorer back to "Common".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding manually the **ProjectReference** block section and specifing a different name

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\F1\Common.csproj">
      <Project>{81379587-a98b-4901-a3ad-266739ecfdb1}</Project>
      <Name>Common1</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\F2\Common.csproj">
      <Project>{b9a1d4dc-465c-4798-8072-6e66ad6719d7}</Project>
      <Name>Common2</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
```